# Importing Facebook SDK into my application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-listview

i am getting a problem when importing a Facebook SDK into my application , attach the Facebook SDK into my android application then that times my R.Java file has been deleted automatically ..

please give me a solution..

thank u in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)please build or clean your facebook sdk project

2)your project->property->android->select library of facebook sdk and then build your project..

i hope its
r.java file will create.